# Using Contains inside In

Tags: caml

I have a list that stores various data about folders for an application. Some of these folders have nested folders, some do not. Using a list of strings that represent a substring of the folder's url, I would like to dynamically create a query that will get all the items I need.

To retrieve one folder, and its possible sub folders, I have been using this:

```
<View><Query><Where><Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='URL_Field'/><Value Type='Text'>folderUrlPart</Value>

</Contains></Where></Query></View>"
```

Which works well for one folder. I want to do this with an array of many folders. I've found the  operator almost does what I would like it to do, but it seems to require an exact match between field type and value?

I would like to dynamically create a query like this:

```
<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name='URL_Field'/><Values><Contains>
<Value Type='Text'>folder_Url_Part[0]</Value>

<Value Type='Text'>folder_Url_Part[1]</Value>

...more values here...

</Contains></Values></In></Where></Query></View>
```

Is it possible to use the In operator in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `<In>` wrong. It is only used for Choice/Lookup fields.

What you are looking for is the `Scope="Recursive"` attribute which is placed on the `<View>`

```
<View Scope="Recursive"><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='URL_Field'/><Value Type='Text'>folderUrlPart</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just ended up using a recursive function to build up a caml query that used nested <or> operators for as many items I needed to check for. I modified this: http://buli.waw.pl/caml-query-multiple-conditions-in-and-or-clause/ to suit my needs.